# what does average per capita income mean?

Tags: united-states

According to https://www.census.gov/quickfacts/fact/table/austincitytexas/PST045222 the "Per capita income in past 12 months (in 2022 dollars), 2018-2022" for Austin, TX was $54,673. What does that mean? I assume that's pre-tax income? What about a Google employee that's getting $200k / year in restricted stock units (RSU's) that have yet to fully vest?

And are they getting that info from the IRS? When I did Ctrl + F for "income" in the [2020 Census Informational Bilingual Questionnaire](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/decennial/2020/technical-documentation/questionnaires-and-instructions/questionnaires/2020-informational-questionnaire.pdf) nothing came up so it doesn't seem like that data is coming from the US Census.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The American Community Survey](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/methodology/questionnaires/2023/quest23.pdf) asks for the income (question 43). It includes e.g. bonuses and social security, and is pre-tax.

Unvested google stocks are probably not income yet, so they probably don't count for that year, but will make up for it in some later year.

Note that "per capita" means per actual person, e.g. including children. It is not the average income of just all employees.

Comment: Additional note: it also isn't per household, which is another common statistic that is seen.